# Non appx extensions are not allowed for payload packages targeting older platforms - While creating UWP Package

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to create an App Package from my UWP application to upload it to the Windows Store, but I get an error telling me this:

> 0x80080215 - Non appx extensions are not allowed for payload packages targeting older platforms.

Here my setup.

Solutions With 2 projects:

- UWP Application
- Universal Windows Class Labrary (dll)

Environment:

- Win11 - (Fully updated)
- VS2022 Pro - (Fully updated)

I've try merging the class library into the main project, but still have the same issue.
I've try different target Windows Version
I've try to deploy only the x64.

Any one have a idea on how to fix this?

[image: Target Windows Version]
[image: Package configuration]

Comment: Will it success if you just package the UWP app without the library?

Comment: Hi Roy, No it won't.

Answer (score 0):

I had to recreate the UWP projet, to resolve the issue.

Comment: Gald to hear the good news!

Answer (score 0):

Same issue.
Solved running a Build > Clean solution.